# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_{n}}|X|\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $X$ is an integrable random variable and $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of events such that $A_{n}\downarrow\varnothing$. Prove that
\begin{align*}
x_{n} = \left\{\int_{A_{n}}|X|\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\right\}
\end{align*}
is a non-decreasing sequence such that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_{n}}|X|\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} = 0
\end{align*}

This is what I have tried:

Let us define the measure $\mu$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mu(A) = \int_{A}|X|\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
\end{align*}

Due to continuity property of the measure, one concludes that
\begin{align*}
0 = \mu(\varnothing) = \mu\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}A_{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A_{n}}|X|\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
\end{align*}

Can someone criticize my solution?

Comment: Well, this is perfectly fine for the given question. However, notice that you basically restated the question in other words, i.e., prove that $\mu$ is measure. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @CaioLins Yes, I do. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can also apply the dominated convergence theorem to $X 1_{A_n}$.